# What exactly is Parent in getView() method

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, layout-inflater, getview

I guess the "parent" here is the actual listView i put in the `activity_main` layout...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View heroListItem = converView;
    if(heroListItem == null)
    {
        heroListItem=LayoutInflater.from(Context).inflate(*a layout*,parent,false)
    }

    //the rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: You can say `null` for `parent` if it doesn't have one. (i.e. it's not already added in teh ViewHierarcy nested under another view (its parent)

Comment: Yeah i could have added null,but i just want to know if parent regarding the current row?which it must be the listView?

Comment: yes. If you look in the HierarchyViewer it'll show you